# Order SQL Query Depending on Value of Previous Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I designed a database in which I store all the information required to perform a process. By 'Process', I mean a succession of multiple steps, or in other words, a recipe. Each recipe (Task in my case) contains several steps. A given step can appear in different recipes.

Here is a sample of the 3 tables I have (with random data):

**Process Table**

```
+----+------+------+--------+-----------+
| ID | Task | Step | NextID | StartHere |
+----+------+------+--------+-----------+
|  1 |    2 |    1 |      4 | TRUE      |
|  2 |    2 |    5 |      8 | FALSE     |
|  3 |    4 |    5 |      9 | FALSE     |
|  4 |    2 |    2 |      2 | FALSE     |
|  5 |    4 |    2 |      6 | FALSE     |
|  6 |    4 |    4 |      3 | FALSE     |
|  7 |    4 |    1 |      5 | TRUE      |
|  8 |    2 |   15 |      0 | FALSE     |
|  9 |    4 |   15 |      0 | FALSE     |
+----+------+------+--------+-----------+
```

**Task Table**

```
+--------+--------------+
| TaskID |   TaskName   |
+--------+--------------+
|      1 | Buy Disk     |
|      2 | Play Disk    |
|      3 | Buy Digital  |
|      4 | Play Digital |
+--------+--------------+
```

**Step Stable**

```
+--------+-----------------+
| StepID |    StepName     |
+--------+-----------------+
|      1 | Turn Console On |
|      2 | Log In          |
|      4 | Insert Disk     |
|      5 | Open Game       |
|     15 | Enjoy           |
+--------+-----------------+
```

Here is the **Process** table above, but with the actual names of Steps and Tasks. It may be easier to understand with this table:

```
+----+--------------+-----------------+--------+-----------+
| ID |     Task     |      Step       | NextID | StartHere |
+----+--------------+-----------------+--------+-----------+
|  1 | Play Disk    | Turn Console On |      4 | TRUE      |
|  2 | Play Disk    | Open Game       |      8 | FALSE     |
|  3 | Play Digital | Open Game       |      9 | FALSE     |
|  4 | Play Disk    | Log In          |      2 | FALSE     |
|  5 | Play Digital | Log In          |      6 | FALSE     |
|  6 | Play Digital | Insert Disk     |      3 | FALSE     |
|  7 | Play Digital | Turn Console On |      5 | TRUE      |
|  8 | Play Disk    | Enjoy           |      0 | FALSE     |
|  9 | Play Digital | Enjoy           |      0 | FALSE     |
+----+--------------+-----------------+--------+-----------+
```

As shown, in the **Process** table, each record(row) represents a combination of Task and step. The `NextID` column contains the ID of the Next Task-Step combination when following the recipe. A `NextID` of `0` marks the end of the task. The `StartHere` Column is a Boolean that specify the first step to be performed depending on the task.

Following that logic, in order to 'Play a Digital Game', you need to start by Turning on the console, then Logging In, then Opening the Game, and finally Enjoying your game session.

My question is:
I want to find a way to query all the steps required for completing a given task and order them in the appropriate order (the order in which they should be performed according to the **Process** table). Does someone have an idea of how this can be done (in one query if possible)?

Basically, the query should first get the `StepName` of the row where `StartHere` is `TRUE`, then get the `StepName` of the row that have an `ID` equals the `NextID` of the previous row and so on.

I came up with the following query, but off course this does not give me the correct order:

```
SELECT Step.StepName 
FROM Step
    INNER JOIN Process ON Step.StepID = Process.Step
    INNER JOIN Task ON Process.Task = Task.TaskID
WHERE Task.TaskID = 4
ORDER BY Process.NextID
```

Any help of hint is welcome!

Thank you

**EDIT**: AS requested in the comments, here is the expected result of such query if it was done for the 'Play Digital' Task:

```
+-----------------+
|    StepNane     |
+-----------------+
| Turn Console On |
| Log In          |
| Open Game       |
| Enjoy           |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: please post the expected result

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Thank you for the proposition. I added the expected results to the Post.

Comment: version of sql server?

Comment: It seems like you just need to `order by Task, Step`. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CTE, get child node principle in a form of Next id...

```
declare @mytable table
(id int,
task varchar(50),
step varchar(50),
nextid int
)


insert into @mytable
values 
(  1 ,'Play Disk    ','Turn Console On ',      4 ),
(  2 ,'Play Disk   ','Open Game       ',      8 ),
(  3 ,'Play Digital ','Open Game       ',      9 ),
(  4 ,'Play Disk    ','Log In          ',      2 ),
(  5 ,'Play Digital ','Log In          ',     6 ),
(  6 ,'Play Digital ','Insert Disk     ',     3 ),
(  7 ,'Play Digital ','Turn Console On ',      5 ),
(  8 ,'Play Disk    ','Enjoy           ',      0 ),
(  9 ,'Play Digital ','Enjoy           ',      0 )


;with mycte
as 
(
 select * from @mytable  where id = 1 -- to start from this ID, if you want this your START here column with true then eventually you will have multiple outputs
 union all
 select t.* from @mytable t
 inner join mycte c on c.nextid = t.id
 )
select * from mycte;
```

Result, Start from 1

```
id  task            step                nextid
1   Play Disk       Turn Console On     4
4   Play Disk       Log In              2
2   Play Disk       Open Game           8
8   Play Disk       Enjoy               0
```

Result, Start from 7

```
id  task            step                nextid
7   Play Digital    Turn Console On     5
5   Play Digital    Log In              6
6   Play Digital    Insert Disk         3
3   Play Digital    Open Game           9
9   Play Digital    Enjoy               0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Never heard about CTEs, but after your post, I went and did a bit of research and couldn't believe how useful they are! It opens up a whole new range of things you could do! I think everybody should go learn about Common Table Expressions...

Comment: If I understand correctly, the first `SELECT` Statement in the CTE Query Definition should return only one row so that you always get the same result after the recursion is completed. That's why you filter by `ID` in the `WHERE` clause, instead of the `StartHere` Boolean column right?

Comment: Correct.. that's your parent or base query

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [LEAD or LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) needed for getting the NextID.

Answer (score 0):

It can be written using DB Cursor and Dynamic query.

So the idea is, open a DB Cursor for `Process` table where `NextID` is `TRUE`.

Inside the Cursor, create a dynamic query:

1. First select values from Cursor variables.
2. Union with - select values where `NextID` = Cursor `NextID`
3. Repeat 2 until `NextID` = 0
4. Execute dynamic query

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It seems to be what I need. Can you please give an example?

Comment: first of all don't use cursor, the solution is CTE get all the child where the child is the next number.

Comment: I agree, cursor is not a wise option to use. CTE is suitable for this.